# OpenGL iOS 2d 4 inch display

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I'm trying to get a 4 inch display working correctly in a 2d OpenGL iOS app.  It works fine with 3.5 inch displays and all IPad displays, but chops off the bottom 88 pixels in 4 inch displays.  I've tried different versions of Launch Images and no Launch Image at all.  I've also tried different variations of MainWindow.xib and no .xib at all.

The OpenGL example in Xcode 5 works well for 3d apps, but I've had big problems with it trying to convert to 2d.  The code I'm using is based on the older GLSprite sample.

It seems to manifest itself when creating the Frame Buffer.  In the following backingHeight is always returned as 480 pixels when it should be 568. Thanks.

```
- (BOOL)createFramebuffer
{
    glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &viewFramebuffer);
    glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &viewRenderbuffer);

    glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, viewFramebuffer);
    glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);
    [context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES fromDrawable:(id<EAGLDrawable>)self.layer];
    glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);

    glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &backingWidth);
    glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT_OES, &backingHeight);

    if(glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES) {
        NSLog(@"failed to make complete framebuffer object %x", glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES));
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Thanks everybody for responding.  I admit I really don't know what I'm doing when setting up the views and frame buffer.  The following is how the initial view is set up.  It refers to something called a "nib file," which I can't seem to find.  Is there any place in this code where I should put the view size logic?  I also said I tried to do it without an .xib file, but I was wrong.  I don't mind using GLKit, but I haven't found a simple example that renders 2d background textures like I want to do.

```
//The GL view is stored in the nib file. When it's unarchived it's sent -initWithCoder:
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder
{
    if((self = [super initWithCoder:coder])) {
        // Get the layer
        CAEAGLLayer *eaglLayer = (CAEAGLLayer*) self.layer;

        eaglLayer.opaque = YES;
        eaglLayer.drawableProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                        [NSNumber numberWithBool:FALSE], kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking, kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8, kEAGLDrawablePropertyColorFormat, nil];

        context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES1];

        if(!context || ![EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context] || ![self createFramebuffer]) {
            [self release];
            return nil;
        }

        animating = FALSE;
        displayLinkSupported = FALSE;
        animationFrameInterval = 1;
        displayLink = nil;
        animationTimer = nil;

        // A system version of 3.1 or greater is required to use CADisplayLink. The NSTimer
        // class is used as fallback when it isn't available.
        NSString *reqSysVer = @"3.1";
        NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
        if ([currSysVer compare:reqSysVer options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
            displayLinkSupported = TRUE;

        [self setupView];
        [self drawView];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The line responsible for this is `[context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES fromDrawable:(id<EAGLDrawable>)self.layer];`. If the returned value for height is always 480 then the view itself is most likely having a height of 480 (try to confirm that).

If so then I guess the quickest approach of finding what setts it to this height is overriding `setFrame:` method and adding a breakpoint.

Comment: That's the bug, but perhaps not the root of the problem. @user3633620: Part of the reason the Xcode 5 (and newer) OpenGL ES Game template works well on all display sizes is that it uses [`GLKView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKView_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html). The code you're using is both old (it's using ES1.1 extension names for features that are core in ES2+), and doing a lot more work than you need to do yourself (and hence exposing you to a lot more bugs & maintenance issues).

Comment: The GLKView is just a wrapper binding the UIView and the openGL. The only reson for its existance is to help people that do not want to go too deep into openGL. I would never use it nor would I recommend it to anyone as it turns out it generates more issues then it solves. As for the ES 1 vs 2 if the fixed pipeline suits your needs it should perform better then the non fixed (Not sure it does though). Anyway this code is legit and should work...

Comment: Thanks for answering, everybody.  I was able to add:  [self setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,568)] to the view initialization code above, and it worked.  However, is there a way to figure out what device size is being used?  Thanks.

Comment: Again, thanks everybody. I was able to use CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] to get the screen height and used setFrame as Matic suggested.  I agree with Matic, and would rather use OpenGL because GLKView is too messy.

Comment: You generally do not need to find the screen bounds. You usually set the openGL view's size in its view controller. The view controller itself already contains a view by defat which size equals to the screen size. If possible try to use that. I did not mean for you to override that method to force the screen value but to simply find out what calles that method with wrong parameters and fix it there.